# How to check out files in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs

I am creating a tool which initially needs a user to connect to TFS. It is my first time to know about it and I would have to code the connection without actually testing it because my machine is not in domain. I would just like to know the basics of it, specifically checking out files. I've searched that to check out files, it needs to have a workspace.

I am using c# language, by the way.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer.aspx) that provides example code for a C# console app that demonstrates programmatically connecting and checking out files with Team Foundation Server 2010 and above.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the workspace from the file you want to check out, as follows:

```
string localPath = @"c:\ws\myfile.cs";
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServer));

// Get a reference to Version Control.              
_versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

_workspace = _versionControl.TryGetWorkspace(localPath);

if (_workspace == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Workspace is not mapped");
}
```